# How can I correctly align the nodes of this TikZ picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have the following TikZ picture:

[image]

and I would like to have my nodes aligned in the way indicated in red.

How can this be done?

What I have so far is pretty messy and I don’t see how to achieve what I want in an elegant way...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',thick,large-box/.style={draw,rounded corners,minimum width=30em,minimum height=3em,align=center},box/.style={draw,rounded corners,minimum width=10em,minimum height=3em,align=center},frame/.style={dashed,black}]
\node[large-box] (solver) {Solver};
\node[box,above=of solver,xshift=7.5em] (checker) {Checker};
\node[box,above=of checker] (parser) {Parser};
\node[above=of parser,font=\bfseries,minimum width=10em,align=center] (query) {Query};
\node[above=of solver,left=of query,font=\bfseries,minimum width=10em,align=center] (model) {Model};
\node[box,below=of solver,xshift=7.5em] (simplifier) {Simplifier};
\node[below=of simplifier,align=center,font=\bfseries,align=center] (simplification) {Simplification};
\node[below=of solver,left=of simplification,font=\bfseries] (solution) {Solution};
\draw[->] (model) -> ([xshift=-7.5em]solver.north);
\draw[->] (query) -> (parser);
\draw[->] (parser) -> (checker);
\draw[->] (checker) -> ([xshift=7.5em]solver.north);
\draw[->] (simplifier) -> (simplification);
\draw[->] (solver) |- ++(0,-1) -| (simplifier);
\draw[->] (solver) |- ++(0,-1) -| (solution);
\draw[frame] ([yshift=-9.2em,xshift=-16.5em]solver) rectangle ([yshift=3em,xshift=9em]parser);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the path operator `|-` in the paths:

```
\draw[->] (model) -> (model|-solver.north);
```

And also in the node positioning:

```
\node[font=\bfseries] (solution) at (model|-simplification) {Solution};
```

**Fixes:**

- The alignment problem was due to the fact that Solution was much shorter in height than Simplification, because this last one has a "P" in it which goes below. This has been fixed by adding the same `text depth` to both nodes.
- Solution and simplification are now at the same distance from the center of Solver.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',thick,large-box/.style={draw,rounded corners,minimum width=30em,minimum height=3em,align=center},box/.style={draw,rounded corners,minimum width=10em,minimum height=3em,align=center},frame/.style={dashed,black}]
\node[large-box] (solver) {Solver};
\node[box,above=of solver,xshift=7.5em] (checker) {Checker};
\node[box,above=of checker] (parser) {Parser};
\node[above=of parser,font=\bfseries,minimum width=10em,align=center] (query) {Query};

\node[xshift=-7.5em,font=\bfseries,minimum width=10em,align=center] (model) at (query.west-|solver.north) {Model};
\node[box,below=of solver,xshift=7.5em] (simplifier) {Simplifier};
\node[below=of simplifier,align=center,font=\bfseries, text depth=1ex] (simplification) {Simplification};
\node[font=\bfseries, text depth=1ex] (solution) at (model|-simplification) {Solution};
\draw[->] (model) -> (model|-solver.north);
\draw[->] (query) -> (parser);
\draw[->] (parser) -> (checker);
\draw[->] (checker) -> (checker|-solver.north);
\draw[->] (simplifier) -> (simplification);
\draw[->] (solver) |- ++(0,-1) -| (simplifier);
\draw[->] (solver) |- ++(0,-1) -| (model|-solution.north);
\draw[frame] ([yshift=-9.2em,xshift=-16.5em]solver) rectangle ([yshift=3em,xshift=9em]parser);

% arrow to check height, you can delete this.
\draw[red] (solution.base) --++ (6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Is it possible to move "model" and "solution" nodes to the left so that they are at equal distance from the middle of the figure than "query" and "simplification"? Moreover, "solution" seems to be lower than "simplification", it is normal?

Comment: @nomis Ah yes. Let me fix that.

Comment: @nomis See updated answer.